# Ajax take data from php fault

Tags: javascript, ajax

In a php file (ajax_chart.php) I have this

```html
$search=$_POST['present'];
if(!empty($search)){
      
        include '../main_includes/connect_db.php';
        $present_day = date("d");
        $present_month = date("m");
        $present_year = date("y");
        for ($i=0;$i<=23;$i++){
        $total_visitors_present=[];
        $query="SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE visitor_day=$present_day AND visitor_hour=$i AND visitor_minute<=59   ";
        $select_query= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $num_visitors[$i]= intval(mysqli_num_rows($select_query));
        array_push($total_visitors_present, $num_visitors);
        
        }
        echo json_encode($total_visitors_present[0]);
        
}
```

and in another php file (charts.php) in script tag I have the following Ajax code

```js
$.ajax({
                url: 'includes/ajax_chart.php',
                data:{present:'present'},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                     if(!data.error){
                        console.log(data); 
                     }   
                    }
            });
```

The console output is weird.

while that i expected to output is the following array
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
What am I doing wrong?
How i retrieve the array with ajax?

Comment: What are the data types of `visitor_day`, `visitor_hour, and `visitor_minute` columns? They might need to be put inside quotes.

Comment: Add  `dataType: "json",` in you AJAX

Comment: I tried without effect.The variables are integers

Comment: What exactly is your console output?

Comment: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: previous in C:\xampp\htdocs\newstheme\admin\includes\ajax_chart.php on line <i>21</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>  All this weird things ...